# SIGABRT error Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, segue, sigabrt

I have tried to do various things to fix this SIGABRT error, I know it's very common but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my error:

```
2013-10-09 22:16:41.277 Tap![4895:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<gameViewController 0x9944780> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tapAction.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017365e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014b98b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017c66a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0117ac2e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x010e6f3b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x010e6493 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0114894a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x004cdcd5 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cb7d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01731b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x004cc82e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x0075f38f -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 220
    12  UIKit                               0x0075f988 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 88
    13  UIKit                               0x0075fa59 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cb874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    15  UIKit                               0x0022dc8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    16  UIKit                               0x0022dc18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    17  UIKit                               0x003256d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    18  UIKit                               0x00325a9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    19  UIKit                               0x00324d4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    20  UIKit                               0x0026b0cd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    21  UIKit                               0x0026bd34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    22  UIKit                               0x0023fa36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    23  UIKit                               0x00229d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016bf8af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x016bf23b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x016dc30e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x016dbb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x016db94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x036879d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x036877fe GSEventRun + 104
    31  UIKit                               0x0022c94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    32  Tap!                                0x00003add main + 141
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d72725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have looked at the related classes and they do not have any problem. This problem occurs when I try to use a Segue.

Comment: Problem is in your nib file check it.

Comment: I am using a Storyboard, storyboard's are not supposed to have a nib file?

Comment: Check your storyboard file in gameViewController, look like this is old IBOutlets connected but not existing anymore.

Comment: Do you mind adding the segue code ?

Comment: Also add breakpoint to All Exception.